# resizing image while dragging and dropping in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

We're trying to make a school project like an online delivery system.. but it will have a little tweak like drag and drop system and food customization. Like when you drag a sauce to the main image which is a bowl of rice. it would automatically change the image to a rice with sauce. sane as protein veggies and more.

I'm trying to figure out how to change image or adopting it to the main image while i drag and drop it also.. changing some of its attributes in CSS.

Also maybe there's a function that when I drag a specific image it would change the main image to a different image not the dragged one.

```js
function doFirst(){
 mypic = document.getElementById('img1');
 mypic.addEventListener("dragstart", startDrag, false);

 mypictwo = document.getElementById('img2');
 mypictwo.addEventListener("dragstart", startDrag2, false);

 mypicthree = document.getElementById('img3');
 mypicthree.addEventListener("dragstart", startDrag3, false);

 mypicfour = document.getElementById('img4');
 mypicfour.addEventListener("dragstart", startDrag4, false);

     leftbox = document.getElementById("mainbox");
     leftbox.addEventListener("dragenter", function(e) {e.preventDefault();}, false);
     leftbox.addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {e.preventDefault();}, false);
     leftbox.addEventListener("drop", dropped, false);
}

//--------------startDrag FUNCTIONS -----------------------//
function startDrag(e){
 var code = '<img id="img1" src="images/image1.jpg">';
 e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', code);
}
function startDrag2(e){
 var code = '<img id="img2" src="images/image2.jpg">';
 e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', code);
}
function startDrag3(e){
 var code = '<img id="img2" src="images/image4.jpg">';
 e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', code);
}
function startDrag4(e){
 var code = '<img id="img2" src="images/image5.jpg">';
 e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', code);
}
//--------------startDrag FUNCTIONS -----------------------//

function dropped(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 leftbox.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
 var code = '<img id="centerimg" src="images/center.png">';
 ondrop

}
function drop(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 var code = '<img id="img2" src="images/image5.jpg" width="300px" height="300px">' ;
}
window.addEventListener ("load", doFirst, false);
```

```css
#centerimg{
 width:500px;
 height: 500px;

}
#img2, #img1, #img3, #img4{
 width:150px;
 height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
 <script src="drag.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3" id="1box"> 
    <img id="img1" src="images/image1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3" id="2box">
    <img id="img2" src="images/image2.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3" id="3box">
    <img id="img3" src="images/image4.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3" id="4box">
    <img id="img4" src="images/image5.jpg">
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <center><div class="col-md-push-4 col-md-4 mainbox" ondrop="drop(event)" id="mainbox"> 
    <img id="centerimg" src="images/center.png">
  </div></center>
 </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: With javascript you can add classes to DOM elements, so you could create a class called like "being-dragged", and define it with having height and width to a reduced form. Then onDrag, add the class to the image being dragged.

Comment: specificaly how can you do that? please help

Comment: Just look online on how to add classes to dom elements, it's really easy